# Can it transform one map with number of .dita file into one html file using dita-ot 3.0？

Tags: html, dita-ot

Background： I have a ditamap file with 7 .dita files. Using the default dita-ot 3.0 html5 plugin, I get 7 html files and one index.html.

Question: Can it output the map file with 7 dita file into only one html file (structured in map or index.html)?   How?

Thanks in advance.

Note: because of topic-based writing, information is divided into mini blocks, while for the output in this forms, the whole document seems to isolate. Users need to do many clicks to switch to another topics and hardly can get the big picture of the document. That is why i ask the question. Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is chunking. Simply set the  `chunk="to-content"` attribute on the map root element.